# Change the name of the statistics using tabstat in stata

Tags: statistics, stata, tex

suppose you have this data

```
input x1 x2 x3
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
end
```

then you do this:

```
estpost tabstat x1 x2 x3, stats(mean median var p5 p95 count) c(v)
```

and you want to export it with esttab (potentially in latex, but that's later)

```
esttab, cells("x1(fmt(%9.4f)) x2(fmt(%9.4f)) x3(fmt(%9.4f))") nonumber noobs label collabels("Var1" "Var2" "Var3")  mlabels(none) mtitles("For All") replace
```

This is the output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
                             Var1         Var2         Var3
-----------------------------------------------------------
mean                       4.0000       5.0000       6.0000
p50                        4.0000       5.0000       6.0000
variance                   9.0000       9.0000       9.0000
p5                         1.0000       2.0000       3.0000
p95                        7.0000       8.0000       9.0000
count                      3.0000       3.0000       3.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And my desired output is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
                             Var1         Var2         Var3
-----------------------------------------------------------
Mean                       4.0000       5.0000       6.0000
Median                     4.0000       5.0000       6.0000
Variance                   9.0000       9.0000       9.0000
P5                         1.0000       2.0000       3.0000
P95                        7.0000       8.0000       9.0000
Observations               3.0000       3.0000       3.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily the most elegant solution...but it appears to get your desired output.

```
clear 
input x1 x2 x3
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
end
estpost tabstat x1 x2 x3, stats(mean median var p5 p95 count)  c(v) 
forvalues i = 1/3 {
    matrix x`i'_new  = e(x`i')
    matrix colnames x`i'_new = Mean Median Variance P5 P95 Observations 
    estadd matrix  x`i'_new 
}
esttab, cells("x1_new(fmt(%9.4f)) x2_new(fmt(%9.4f)) x3_new(fmt(%9.4f))") nonumber noobs label collabels("Var1" "Var2" "Var3")  mlabels(none) mtitles("For All") replace
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks ! I know this could be another question, but how can I put Observations row in %9.0f (no decimals)

Comment: Sweet! For that you need six entries in the fmt() options, one for each statistic. So x1_new(...) would become "x1_new(fmt(%9.4f %9.4f %9.4f %9.4f %9.4f %9.0fc))" and so on.